# Merging multiple spreadsheet data within an excel workbook based on unique identifier using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am a graduate student working on some educational research and new to VBA programming within excel. I have survey data from students and I have three different surveys. I have one sheet that is demographic data, I have another sheet that is the pre-curriculum data, and another sheet that is post-curriculum data. My goal is to create a new spreadsheet that is based on the student id number that is the unique identifier in all three sheets and combine all of the data based on the student id. Previously, I have used the VLOOKUP function and successfully made this work but that was a very tedious process and I want to automate this to save time.

So my thought process is to copy the pre-curriculum data (15 columns of data) into the new worksheet, match the demographic data (5 columns) and have it returned to the new worksheet into rows matching the student id, and match the post-curriculum data (15 columns) and have it returned to the new worksheet into rows matching the student id. Not all students who completed the demographics and pre-curriculum completed the post curriculum. The number of students varies from each spreadsheet (~1250-1500 students). I only want to return students who have completed all three spreadsheets to my newly developed worksheet. My motivation for this is to be able to have all the data in one sheet so I can easily load it into a statistical analysis software package and analyze it further.

I have some screenshots to give an idea of what my data looks like and what I'm trying to do. Some information is blacked out for confidentiality purposes.

> This image represents my "Work" spreadsheet where I'm trying to combine all of the data. You will see I have left 5 rows blank because that is where I want to stick the demographic data:

[image: description]

> This image is the 5 columns of demographic information that I want to bring over to the "Work" sheet

[image: description]

I wanted to add a third image that showed the post-curriclum data that I want to return to the "Work" sheet in the rows directly following the pre-curriculum responses but since this is my first post it will only allow me to post two images.

I have some VBA code that I tried but I honestly was nowhere close so it's not even worth embedding in this post. I hope this provides a clear description of what I'm trying to do. If anyone could offer any help to how I should do this that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: StackOverflow is a community that can help you code, but we're not here to write code for you.  Please at least try to get something working and post it here, and read this guide for asking a good Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: VBA isn't a 'Please code this for me' service, and as such your questions doesn't fit our guidelines. My suggestion would be to browse SO and Google to see if others have tackled similar problems. I have tackled this same kind of task using Dictionaries and Arrays, get yourself familiarized with those to get started. If you can't find the resources you need on your own, then a VLOOKUP is going to be your way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This will help me moving forward. I am new to this website and I will remember the etiquette for asking questions from now on. I am not looking for somebody to code it for me just looking to see if anyone could offer suggestions to get me on the correct path. I will try and get something working and ask again if I'm still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AddIn below and see if it does what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm